# Add NodeJS backend code to an Angular-seed based project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I recently abandoned the awesome LAMP solution for Node/AngularJS and I have some serious (and noob) difficulties to begin.
I took an existing AngularJS project based on Angular Seed and I didn't figure out how can I add some backend javascript code.

In online tutorials, I always find an **app.js** file, in which there is some "requires" and where I can add an extra server code. To launch this kind of project I have to `node app.js`

In my Angular-seed based project, there is only a **package.json** that contains script commands. 
Also, I noticed that to launch it, I have to `npm start`.

Where can I put my NodeJS code in this project ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can put your code anywhere you like, `npm start` is just a shorthand for smth like `npm app.js` or `npm server.js`

Answer (score 1):

Usually you will have two differents projects. The backend (Nodejs) and the frontend (Angular). You can expose your backend logic using a public API that your frontend will use. For example you can expose a REST API using nodejs with help of express. I recommend you to take a look at swagger that can help you to define your api.

After that using your angular app you can send different requests to that API and consume the info that receive from it.

To sum up you will have two different projects. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! Actually, that's exactly what I want. However, if I start two projects, I necessarily have to make them listen two different ports (in which case I will have a Same origin policy problem for the API calls, but for some reasons I'm not allowed to Access-Control-Allow-Origin). Is there a way to have two projects listening at the same port ?

Comment: @J.Doe If you want to run the project on same port, create node js file in your angular project as [server.js](https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli)

Comment: You can create the nodejs file in your angular project as @k11k2 said. Or you can allow CORS in your project from known addresses and hosts

Comment: Thanks to both of you ! However, if I create a server.js file, I don't know how to run it in the same context then the project. The script line _start_ in _package.json_ contains this
`http-server -a localhost -p 4000 -c-1 ./app` 
(Also, I'm not allowed to use the CORS option in my project)

Comment: That will be a different question. Open a new one for that. Try using scripts inside your package.json that you can invoke with npm. Or you can use gulp tasks for that

Comment: @J.Doe Go through the link I mentioned in above comment. There you can find enough information.